# initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level - Swift 4 iOS

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

I'm a bit new to Swift programming so forgive me if this seems silly.  I have a class outside my ViewController that I want to instantiate inside the ViewController, but I am getting an error:

**initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level**

The class:

```
public class TappyBleScanner : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

      public var manager : CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue : nil)

      public init(){} //based on other posts, I thought this would solve it
}
```

The code in the ViewController:

```
    public func scanForTappyBle() {

    var tappyScanner : TappyBleScanner = TappyBleScanner() //<- This is where Xcode 9 reports the error


}
```

Other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859139/initializer-is-inaccessable-due-to-internal-protection-level) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249531/why-does-a-public-class-struct-in-swift-require-an-explicit-public-initializer/40251059) suggest that making an empty public initializer explicitly would solve this, but the error persists. The Swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3) seems to suggest that the public no argument init() function would have allowed external modules to access the initializer and hence instantiate this class:

> If you want a public type to be initializable with a no-argument
>   initializer when used in another module, you must explicitly provide a
>   public no-argument initializer yourself as part of the type’s
>   definition.

However the error still persists, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't even compile what you had (Xcode 9.2). You need to override init().  And you can't use self in a static initialization of manager.

If you change your TappyBleScanner to the following, it'll compile and run. :)

```
public class TappyBleScanner : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    public var manager : CBCentralManager?

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue : nil)
    }

    public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I provided just a code snippett so there's not too much to look at.  I originally used the overide init() like that and the same error was produced, even tried marking it public explicitly and no luck.  I suspect now there's something wrong with the project configuration because this morning it seems to not even be finding the dependencies at all (undeclared type errors and such), and I didn't change anything except reboot.  I'm new to XCode too.  I'll get the dependencies/references working again and try your suggestion